# How to use a method across multiple activities and in my recycler adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making an Android timer application using Java and Android Studio.
I have the following simple time converter method which converts milliseconds to seconds then formats seconds to ss:mm which is used in two different activities:

```
private String convertTime(long time) {
        int mins = (int) (time / 1000) / 60;
        int secs = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", mins, secs);
    }
```

I also have a very similar method for use in my recycler adapter, but it doesn't convert to seconds:

```
private String convertTime(long time) {
        int mins = (int) time / 60;
        int secs = (int) time % 60;
        return  String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", mins, secs);
    }
```

Which is the best way to implement this method so there is minimal reused code? I initially created an interface and implemented the method where needed, but I don't think this is the best way. Thanks.

Comment: Create a `TimeConversionUtils` class and put both methods there. rename them appropriatelly. Use `TimeConversionUtils.methodA(...)` or `TimeConversionUtils.methodB(...)` where necessary. zero code duplication, all contained in the same place. As it's currently written in your question, MethodB could internally use MethodA(time/1000) and even have chaining going on.

Comment: in java you have something like `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.UK).format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))` which you can use in some kind of static method of some `TimeUtility` class and use it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `TimeUtils.java` class like this:

```
public class TimeUtils
{
    public static String convertTime1(long time)
    {
        int mins = (int) (time / 1000) / 60;
        int secs = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", mins, secs);
    }

    public static String convertTime2(long time)
    {
        int mins = (int) time / 60;
        int secs = (int) time % 60;
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", mins, secs);
    }
}
```

And then, use `TimeUtils.convertTime1(1000)` for example, to access these functions any where.

Comment: Thank you this has worked! Would this be an example of a helper class?

Comment: Glad I helped. Yes this can be a helper class. You can upvote my answer if it helped you.